# Spring boot @RequestBody default POJO mapping behavior?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a java class with uppercase field names and some of them with under scroll, like this:

```java
public class DATADto {
  private String UPPERCASE;
  private String UNDER_SCROLL;

  public String getUPPERCASE() { return UPPERCASE; }
  public void setUPPERCASE(String s) { UPPERCASE = s; }
  ...//setters and getters
}
```

and I used this in a rest endpoint that accepts json in a spring rest controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api/path"})
public class MyRestController {
   @PostMapping(path = {"/Data"}, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

    public ResponseEntity<?> useDATADto(@RequestBody DATADto aDATADto ) {
     //do something
    }
}
```

what JSON fields do I need to send by default and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story goes like this..

Spring Boot by default uses Jackson ObjectMapper to serialize and deserialize Java objects.

In this context, by serialization we mean the conversion of java objects into json, deserialization is the reverse process.

Regarding the `@RequestBody` annotation, the following is written in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html):

> Annotation indicating a method parameter should be bound to the body
> of the web request. The body of the request is passed through an
> HttpMessageConverter to resolve the method argument depending on the
> content type of the request. Optionally, automatic validation can be
> applied by annotating the argument with @Valid.

In short, `@RequestBody` annotation tells Spring to deserialize an incoming request body into an object passed as a parameter to the handler method. Spring achieves this using [MessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/converter/MessageConverter.html#fromMessage-org.springframework.messaging.Message-java.lang.Class-)

Since Spring Boot uses `Jackson` by default for serializing and deserializing request and response objects in your REST APIs, and Jackson uses `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, so that will be message converter implementation that spring will use. You can read more about that [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html).

The important thing is that Jackson uses [Java Bean naming](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) conventions to figure out  the json properties in a Java class. Acutally it uses default [`PropertyNamingStrategy`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html) . Here is what is written in documentation:

> In absence of a registered custom strategy, default Java property
> naming strategy is used, which leaves field names as is, and removes
> set/get/is prefix from methods (as well as lower-cases initial
> sequence of capitalized characters).

So, since you didn't set any naming strategy, it will use default one.

Beacause of that, if you send payload like this :

```
{
    "uppercase": "YOUR_VALUE",
    "under_scroll": "YOUR_VALUE"
}
```

That won't work, you will get exception, since there jackson won't find `under_scroll` property in your class, it will look for  `under_SCROLL` , therefore this payload:

```
{
    "uppercase": "YOUR_VALUE",
    "under_SCROLL": "YOUR_VALUE"
}
```

will work.

To change default `PropertyNamingStrategy` check
[this](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring/spring-jackson-property-naming-strategy/) article.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the Jackson property naming strategy. The default is `LOWER_CAMEL_CASE` , so your request body should look like this:

```json
{
    "uppercase": "test",
    "under_scroll": "test"
}
```

For all possible configurations of the naming strategy for Jackson please refer to the document [«Class PropertyNamingStrategy»](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html)

If you're using Spring, you may use this property to configure the naming strategy:

```js
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy
```

Another possible way will be the bean configuration:

```java
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
     Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonMapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
     jacksonMapper.propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CASE);
     return jacksonMapper;
}
```

**Additional note:**

Your current naming approach doesn't follow the Java Code Conventions. If you need to process JSON with some specific naming format better to use the `@JsonProperty` annotation on the fields of your POJO.

Please see the example below:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class DATADto {
    @JsonProperty("UPPERCASE")
    private String uppercase;
    @JsonProperty("UNDER_SCROLL")
    private String underScroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the configuration property, what worked for me is { “uppercase”:”val1”, “under_SCROLL”:”val2” } which is strange.

Comment: About the java naming convention, you’re right, this code doesn’t follow it, but it’s written this way and I can’t change it.

Answer (score 0):

You should send post request to `/api/path/data` with this request body:

```
{
    "uppercase": "YOUR_VALUE",
    "under_scroll": "YOUR_VALUE"
}
```

Comment: Why? Some documentation reference please.

Comment: @alibttb you can also check this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body#@requestbody

Comment: This won't work.